# Значение switch.Можно ли вставить букву,вместо числа

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a;
cout<<"Letter = ";
cin >> a;
switch (a) {
    case 1 :cout<<"One";
    break;
}
return 0;

}
```

Вот я хотел спросить,вместо чисел в case, можно использовать буквы?Например case 'A':cout<<"Number";И еще вопрос,вот когда я запускаю программу,то Letter =1.Как-то некрасиво получается,как сделать так,чтобы =1 было раздельно,вот так Letter = 1. [Проблема с cin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPdsZ.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPdsZ.png)

Comment: Можно. Вставляй.

Comment: Можно, но если вы вводите `cin >> a`, где `a` - `int`, то вы не можете *ввести букву*.